# How to select text in PDF file in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, pdf

I am right now working with one pdf based application in ipad. Now i am able to display the pdf file in the ipad,but now i want to show some annotation based operations on the same pdf file. and for the same purpose,i need to select the text.Is there any function available that may help to select the text to perform the operations?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : 
I surfed net and found some code that was helpful for UITouch in the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570108/comparing-touch-coordinates)
but am not getting way to implement it for my purpose. Can Somebody show me a path?

Kindly show me a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best resource I have found on SO so far: [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints). Maybe it will help. There is nothing on selecting text specifically, but maybe the "Getting raw test" and "Searching" sections will help you.